# How to implement the geo location autocomplete on searching similar to what foursquare official website do?

Tags: android, autocomplete, foursquare, geonames

I am trying to build my android app with foursquare api, It works fine by using their api
[foursquare search venue](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) with "near" parameter and the value "Paris".

But before calling this link, I want to have an autocomplete textbox to help users for searching, however I couldn't find any api to do this. (their [suggestcompletion api](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/suggestcompletion) need to pass the location/geoname as well, that's not what I want)

In their official website / official mobile app, their autocomplete is extremely good. It accepts country name, district name or even a venue name.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: see this google provide place api https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place

Comment: Hi @Haresh, thanks for the reply, but this api seems only returning the complete name without any lat and lng. As it is from google, I don't think the place name could be searched accurately in foursquare.

Comment: FYI: You can use Google Places textsearch endpoint for autocomplete suggestions and that one does return lat/lng or you use the reference provided the autocomplete to get the lat/lng from the details endpoint. Just play around with it a little bit, may be a cleaner option. I am happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found that I need to use a webservice from [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/source-code/) to do the autocomplete, and then use it result to pass the lat and lng to foursquare.

A reference from foursquare [link](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/geocode), they use this geonames dataset too.